# MobaXterm custom ssh session port forwarding

Tags: portforwarding, ssh-tunnel, mobaxterm

I have been using mobaXterm to connect to remote ports using a command:
ssh -L 443:192.168.114.01:443 -L 80:192.168.114.01:80 username@[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6hYl8.png)

I want to save ssh sessions for all of these commands I have been copying and pasting, but I don't know how to translate the ports I want to forward to into the ssh session. Any help is appreciated

I tried adding some stuff into the advanced ssh settings section without any luck